# Json Schema allowing additional properties even though additionalProperties is set to false

Tags: json, regex, validation, jsonschema, fastify

**Given the following schema:**

```
export const MESSAGE_SCHEMA = {
  additionalProperties: false,
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    comment: { type: 'string' },
    startAt: { type: 'string' },
    states: {
      type: 'object',
      minProperties: 1,
      patternProperties: {
        "^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9 ]{0,127}$": {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            type: { type: 'string', enum: TASK_TYPES_ALL_ENUM },
            next: { type: 'string' },
            end: { type: 'boolean' },
            choices: {
              type: 'array',
              items: {
                type: 'object'
              },
              minItems: 2
            },
            default: { type: 'string' },
            error: { type: 'string' },
            cause: { type: 'string' },
            resource: { type: 'string' },
          },
          required: ['type'],
          allOf: [
            // Make choices required if task type = 'choice'
            {
              if: {
                properties: { type: { const: TASK_TYPE_CHOICE } }
              },
              then: {
                required: ['type', 'choices']
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    }
  },
  required: ['startAt','states']
};
```

If I send a payload into my API with a key within the "states" object that doesn't match the pattern, it always allows the request... **The behavior as I understood should prevent this with the properties / patternProperties + additionalProperties = false, but this is not the case...**

For example - this should error since the pattern does not match and no additional properties are allowed, but I get a response from the API as though it was validated successfully:

```
{
    "eventNamespace": "state",
    "eventType": "transition",
    "payload": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "message": {
        "startAt": "foo",
        "states": {
            "!#@^@^": {
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I then put a value that matches the pattern, I get a validation failure (as expected):

```
{
    "eventNamespace": "state",
    "eventType": "transition",
    "payload": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "message": {
        "startAt": "foo",
        "states": {
            "valid property example": {
                "type": "choice",
                "choices": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "body/message/states/valid property example/choices must NOT have fewer than 2 items"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your schema is fine. When I run it through [my validator](https://metacpan.org/dist/JSON-Schema-Modern/view/script/json-schema-eval) I get:

```
{
  "errors" : [
    {
      "error" : "additional property not permitted",
      "instanceLocation" : "/states/!#@^@^",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/states/additionalProperties"
    },
    {
      "error" : "not all additional properties are valid",
      "instanceLocation" : "/states",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/states/additionalProperties"
    },
    {
      "error" : "not all properties are valid",
      "instanceLocation" : "",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties"
    }
  ],
  "valid" : false
}
```

I suggest you open a bug report for the implementation you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this is because Fastify validator removes additional properties by default.
You can disable this behaviour by setting `removeAdditional: false`:

```
const server = Fastify({
  ajv: {
    customOptions: {
      removeAdditional: false
    }
  }
})
```

For more information https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Validation-and-Serialization/